# 'book' textfield does not trigger event in sencha

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, sencha-architect

I have this code `Ext.get('book').setValue('1');`

> Note: Loads the page and book value is set to 1. Not after page load
>   and book value change to 1.

It sets the book to value 1. But it does not trigger a change event. Is there a way to trigger the change event after page loads?

Edit: 
In html script,

```
<script..>
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        $("book").on("blur", function() {
           //calls other function
        }); // not called as blur is not invoked 
    }); 
</script>

<input id="book" type="book" value="" /><br />
```

In extjs,

```
var panel = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {    
id: 'panel',
columns: [
    var bookid = "new book";
      Ext.Ajax.request({
        params: { bookid: bookid},
        function: function (response) {
           Ext.get('book').setValue(bookid);
           // after setValue, book will receive a change event(e.g .blur in html) and changes other functions 
        }
      });
]
});
```

Comment: yes, set it inside your app initialization

Comment: Is there any other way besides doing in app initialization? Cause it is after page load and then triggering of a button before it comes to setting book textfield value  @Icepickle

Comment: I think you could set a default value as well, but your code sample / question is so limited that it is really hard to see what problems you have. Could you give a more detailed description (edit your start post?)

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax request seems to be malformed, the `function: function` statement would be the place where you put normally `success: function` like in the following statement:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'insert-your-http-endpoint-here',
    params: {
        bookid: bookid
    },
    success: function(response){
        debugger; // -> setting this statement will show that you enter the success statement
        Ext.get('book').setValue(bookid);
    },
    failure: function(response, opts) {
        // something went wrong with your request
        console.log('server-side failure with status code ' + response.status);
    }
});
```

more info about how to use ExtJS or the specific function, you could find in the documentation (check if you have the correct version, ofcourse) which can be found [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Ajax-method-request)

From the above code, you don't need the `debugger` statement, but it could help if you want to check if you actually get into this code block or not, and what happens when you try to set the value.

Also, don't forget to check your console output when something is not working, maybe there was a problem that would be clearly indicated in the console log

Comment: Yup! In my current codes, it is working fine and the textfield has been set. But not the '// after setValue, book will receive a change event(e.g .blur in html) and changes other functions' @Icepickle

Comment: Sorry I did a shortcut but the main functions are showing and is just like your codes

Comment: @Developps: I am unsure what you mean. Do you mean that events set on the html control are not firing, or do you have another control that is listening to these events? The onblur won't fire because you set a value. The onchange would, in case the text is different from the text that was before

Comment: It is the events set on the html control are not firing. I have tried Onchange and it doesn't fire too due to it being set before anything changes @Icepickle

Comment: `$("book").on("change", function() {
           ...
        }); // not called as change is not invoked `

Comment: I found the answer! I just change all the blur to focus instead. So when the page loads, by default it focuses the textfield and it will work @Icepickle